# Nomethod error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to allow logged in listeners to post their meditation notes. So when they logged in, they will see only their notes. I am keep getting undefined error in meditation controller(mymeditationnotes) in create. I am not sure of my new action , whether it works as suppose to.

my mymeditationnoteController

```
class MymeditationnotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_mymeditationnote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_listener!

  def index
    @mymeditationnotes = Mymeditationnote.all.order("created_at DESC")

  end
  def show

  end

  def new
    # @mymeditationnote = Mymeditationnote.new
    @mymeditationnote = current_listener.mymeditationnotes.build


  end

  def edit

  end

  def create

     @mymeditationnote = @current_listener.mymeditationnotes.build(mymeditationnote_params)

    if @mymeditationnote.save
      redirect_to mymeditationnotes_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def find_mymeditationnote
      @mymeditationnote = Mymeditationnote.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def mymeditationnote_params
      params.require(:mymeditationnote).permit(:title, :describe, :divide_distribute)
    end
end
```

my model

```
class Mymeditationnote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listener
end
```

listener model

```
class Listener < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :listeners_speakers, class_name: 'ListenersSpeakers'
  has_many :speakers, through: :listeners_speakers
  has_many :mymeditationnotes

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates_presence_of :time_zone
end
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: undefined method `mymeditationnotes' for #<Listener:0x007f9d2ae1ed98>

Comment: Update your question with your Listener model.

Comment: ok i did, here again the error undefined method `mymeditationnotes' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is that your current error?

Comment: yes it is undefined method `mymeditationnotes' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Where are you set `@current_listener` on `create` action. It is `nil` that's why you getting `'mymeditationnotes' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I put @current_listener to restrict listers to create meditation notes only for themselves.   I dont understand by "where are you set"?